# Recording stereo audio through the output pins of the headset jack, vs writing a usb audio driver

Tags: android, audio, usb, audio-recording

We're a group of students who are assigned to create a mobile app that has to record high quality **stereo** audio. The problem is that most(all?) phones only has mono input in the 3.5mm headset jack. On the iPhone/iOS we can solve this by connecting an external mic in the 30-pin connector, but on android devices we've not found any similar solutions.

According to eXtream Software Development, the developer of USB Audio Recorder PRO, it is not possible to record audio from USB devices on Android without a custom driver.

> eXtream Software Development has written a custom USB audio driver from scratch because Android does not support USB audio (**even Android 4.1 contrary to popular believe!**).
>
> Source: http://www.extreamsd.com/USBAudioRecorderPRO/

As we don't have any experience in writing device drivers we were instead of using a USB mic, and writing our own driver, wondering if it is possible to configure the output pins of the headset jack to input?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Bluetooth A2DP? A2DP is stereo, and with a newer version of Android, you should be able to configure the phone as the receiver.